# Как получить html страничку по http средствами php5

Tags: php, html, http, php5

При попытки загрузить http://zakupki.gov.ru/epz/order/notice/ea44/view/common-info.html?regNumber=0348100062016000210

Ошибка:

```
PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(http://zakupki.gov.ru/epz/order/notice/ea44/view/common-info.html?regNumber=0348100062016000210):
failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 
in test.php on line 5
```

Код скрипта (test.php) :

```
<?php

include 'simple_html_dom.php';

$html = file_get_contents("http://zakupki.gov.ru/epz/order/notice/ea44/view/common-info.html?regNumber=0348100062016000210");

echo $html;
```

Comment: curl http://zakupki.gov.ru/epz/order/notice/ea44/view/common-info.html?regNumber=0348100062016000210
<html>
<head>
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache" charset=UTF-8">
    <title> Страница не найдена </title>
Защита от парсера.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

всё проще чем вы думаете используйте контекст для `file_get_contents`

```
$opts = array(
  'http'=> array(
    'method'=>   "GET",
    'user_agent'=>    'Mozilla/5.0'
  )
); 

$context = stream_context_create($opts); 


$html = file_get_contents("http://zakupki.gov.ru/epz/order/notice/ea44/view/common-info.html?regNumber=0348100062016000210",false,$context);
```

подробнее здесь http://php.net/manual/ru/function.file-get-contents.php и здесь http://php.net/manual/ru/function.stream-context-create.php

Answer (score 1):

Если послать в заголовке User-Agent, то всё работает:

```
curl 'http://zakupki.gov.ru/epz/order/notice/ea44/view/common-info.html?regNumber=0348100062016000210' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36'
```

Перепишите ваш код на использование [cURL](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.curl.php), но лучше воспользуйтесь готовой библиотекой [Guzzle](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle)

Comment: Стыдно должно быть не знать о функциях с 7к репутации, и кто вообще плюсует такие ответы без минимального кода решения.

Comment: Правда? А я думал, что стыдно в 2016 году использовать file_get_contents для HTTP-запросов.